# Update ipywidget dropdown list from function in python

Tags: python, widget, dropdown, ipywidgets

I am new to Python and I want to create an interactive dropdown list from an ipywidget. The main purpose is to update the dropdown list based on two other widgets. In the code below, the widget **plotType** will be updated based on the input from the widgets **headers_x** and **headers_y** (both refer to the dataframe columns selected for plotting). If both **headers_x** and **headers_y** have the *Select* option, then the **plotType** needs to show "*Make selection*". But if the **headers_x** and **headers_y** have other options selected (columns from the dataframe), then the **plotType** needs to change accordingly. If the **headers_x** and **headers_y** are both numeric, then the **plotType** needs to show: *numericVsNumeric*, but if **headers_x** is categorical and **headers_y** is numeric, then **plotType** needs to show '*catergoricalVsNumeric*' I have attempted my solution as follows, but the options in the plotType widget do not update. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

```
from ipywidgets import *
import seaborn.apionly as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

#identifies the columns in the dataframe
df_cols = list(df.columns.values)
df_cols.insert(0, 'Select')
str_cols = list(df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns.values)
str_cols.insert(0, 'Select')

#plot function
def set_plot(headers_x, headers_y, plotType):
    data = df
    #plotting functions to be added

#function to specify the type of plot based on users input
def set_plotType():
    data = df
        #If no selection has been made
    if headers_x.value == 'Select' and headers_y.value == 'Select':
        init = list(['Make Selection'])
    else:
        #if x and y are both numeric
        if data[headers_x.value].dtype == np.float and data[headers_y.value].dtype == np.float:
            init = list(['NumericVsNumeric'])
            #if x is categorical and y is numeric
        elif data[headers_x.value].dtype == np.object and data[headers_y.value].dtype == np.float:
            init = list(['CategoricalVsNumeric'])

    return init


#define widgets
headers_x = widgets.Dropdown(
        options=df_cols,
        value=df_cols[0],
        description='X'
    )

headers_x.set_title  = 'headers_x'

headers_y = widgets.Dropdown(
        options=df_cols,
        value=df_cols[0],
        description='Y'
    )

headers_y.set_title  = 'headers_y'

plotType = widgets.Dropdown(
        options=set_plotType(),
        #value=df_cols[0],
        description='Plot Type'
    )

plotType.set_title  = 'plotType'


#interact function
interact(set_plot, headers_x = headers_x, headers_y = headers_y, plotType = plotType)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I achieved this by using observe. This means whenever your top two drop down options change, they will run the set_Plottype function.

I changed your headers.x AND headers.y to an OR, as you need both defined.

I also gave you a third option for when x is numeric and y is categorical.

```
from ipywidgets import *
import numpy as np
import seaborn.apionly as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

#identifies the columns in the dataframe
df_cols = list(df.columns.values)
df_cols.insert(0, 'Select')
str_cols = list(df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns.values)
str_cols.insert(0, 'Select')

#plot function
def set_plot(headers_x, headers_y, plotType):
    data = df
    #plotting functions to be added

#function to specify the type of plot based on users input
def set_plotType(_):
    data = df
        #If no selection has been made
    if headers_x.value == 'Select' or headers_y.value == 'Select':
        plotType.options = list(['Make Selection'])
    else:
        #if x and y are both numeric
        if data[headers_x.value].dtype == np.float and data[headers_y.value].dtype == np.float:
            plotType.options = list(['NumericVsNumeric'])
            #if x is categorical and y is numeric
        elif data[headers_x.value].dtype == np.object and data[headers_y.value].dtype == np.float:
            plotType.options = list(['CategoricalVsNumeric'])
        elif data[headers_x.value].dtype == np.float and data[headers_y.value].dtype == np.object:
            plotType.options = list(['NumericalVsCategoric'])



#define widgets
headers_x = widgets.Dropdown(
        options=df_cols,
        value=df_cols[0],
        description='X'
    )

headers_x.set_title  = 'headers_x'

headers_y = widgets.Dropdown(
        options=df_cols,
        value=df_cols[0],
        description='Y'
    )

headers_y.set_title  = 'headers_y'

plotType = widgets.Dropdown(
        options=[],
        description='Plot Type'
    )

headers_x.observe(set_plotType)
headers_y.observe(set_plotType)


#interact function
interact(set_plot, headers_x = headers_x, headers_y = headers_y, plotType = plotType)
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much, @ac24. I really appreciate it.